# Apache restart history

Tags: apache

Can someone please assist me.

I am trying to find a log on an Ubuntu server that will show me a history of dates and times when Apache was restarted.

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS
Apache version: 2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

Thanks - Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

apache usually logs to /var/log/apache2 - depending on what log rotation/cleaning you have going on there should at least be an access_log and an error_log (names may change depending on apache config).  In each you should be able to see restart messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had looked at all logs in  /var/log/apache2 and did not see anything that recorded start or start of the web server.

Comment: I get this recorded in my error.log : [Mon Feb 13 23:31:11 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 13 23:31:18 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I found lines you refer to as well as [Thu Feb 09 16:10:14 2012] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart

Comment: The "AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart" message indicates a `service apache2 reload`, while a `service apache2 restart` will lead to something like "AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down". Both have in common that the log sequence ends with "AH00163 [...] resuming normal operations" so I suggest it's best to look out for that in most cases.

Comment: A shorter way of checking for what @tanius mentioned can be read here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15905798/295260

Comment: found in error.log, its not an error so not sure why its there, not access.log for raspian anyway `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log |  grep "shut"`

Answer (score 0):

You could search for `configured` keyword in apache error logs:

```
### for centos/redhat:
egrep -irn 'configured' '/var/log/httpd/error_log'

### for ubunto:
egrep -irn 'configured' '/var/log/apache2/error_log'
```

Answer (score 0):

When we start or restart the apache, we get the logs in `/var/log/apache2/error_logs` with the word **caught SIGTERM, shutting down**

So we can find the error_logs with word **SIGTERM**, will get if apache service start|restart