# How to find out the time apache was last restarted?

Tags: apache, centos, kloxo

I have a VPS with `kloxo` control panel installed. I am using `CentOS 5.8 32-bit`.

I restarted Apache today but forgot the time when I did. It is very important to know the exact time.

Can I find it out using the log files or SSH command?

Comment: This question would be better off at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: @RandomSeed Surely this would be better on http://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Log in into your VPS via SSH and type in the command:

```
grep resuming /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Comment: of course, you need to put the actual path to the log file that your apache has been configured to use

Answer (score 6):

You can find out this from the Apache logs. You will need to log into your VPS via ssh and check the error_log for your apache instance.

You should find something like the following:

```
[Tue Apr 09 11:43:23 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

That will tell you exactly when you apache instance was last started successfully